# Autohide Taskbar on Windows XP Embedded

Tags: taskbar, windows-xp-embedded

I am configuring a HP Thin Client running Windows XP Embedded and I would like to autohide the taskbar.

Generally, system changes can only be made from the Administrator account. Unfortunately, the taskbar properties are not available in the User account built into the machine.

**Can autohide be enabled using the registry or some other mechanism?**

Answer (score 1):

[Hope this solution from TechArena helps](http://forums.techarena.in/tips-tweaks/1179470.htm) Off course you need the rights to change the registry to do this!

> One way to activate the auto- hide
>   taskbar option is via the registry.
>   However, it should be noted that this
>   method is technical in nature and does
>   require some code and registry
>   knowledge.
>
> - **Step 1**. Go to Start and then select Run. In the Run input type
>     regedit
> - **Step 2**. when you enter into registry there you would see the files
>     and folders viewable, then in the
>     registry you may search for
>     HKCU\Software \Microsoft\Windows
>     \CurrentVersion \Explorer\ StuckRects2
> - **Step 3**. once you put the registry key, you will be directed to
>     the Settings. This value is a
>     REG_Binary type. Within this you need
>     to find the settings for the taskbar,
>     as well as you could also make the
>     settings for icon size and icon
>     placement.
> - **Step 4**. whatever the value you put it will get written only when your
>     computer log offs, and it would be
>     difficult to catch the value. You will
>     first have to fiddle around with the
>     environment and then export the data.
> - **Step 5**. Once you have located and exported the data, test to see if
>     the taskbar works properly.